# Showing $\vdash (A\supset (A\supset B)) \supset (A\supset B)$

Tags: logic

I am trying to show that

$$\vdash (A\supset (A\supset B)) \supset (A\supset B)$$

My approach was to start with 
$$\begin{align}
B, A\supset B, A\supset (A\supset B)\vdash (A\supset B) &\qquad(\text{id}) \\
B, A \supset B \vdash (A\supset (A\supset B))\supset(A\supset B) &\qquad(\text{introduction of $\supset$}) \\
B \vdash (A\supset B) \supset ((A\supset (A\supset B))\supset(A\supset B) &\qquad (\text{introduction of $\supset$})
\end{align}$$

But here I get stuck. I wanted to cancel the $A\supset B$ with the $B$ using elimination, but that doesn't seem to work because of the bracketing. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: What book are you using?  Is this logic or metalogic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

Start with:

$1. A \vdash A$

and

$2. A\supset (A\supset B) \vdash A\supset (A\supset B)$

Using $\supset Elim$ on $1$ and $2$:

$3. A, A\supset (A\supset B) \vdash A\supset B$

... see if you can finish from here ... two more steps ...

Comment: How to proceed from when you take $A\supset (A\supset B)$ over?

Comment: @fosho  Don't take it over yet!  First get rid of the $A$ ... HINT: look at 1

Comment: I am very confused, how am I meant to get rid of $A$?

Comment: Wait I think I get it. Am I meant to use $\supset$ elimination on 1 and 3 to get rid of the $A$ on the RHS of 3, which removes that $A$ on the RHS, then take $A$ (from the left) over, then the second term over which willl complete things?

Comment: @fosho Yes, correct!  Oh, so yes, it's actually three more steps then, not two, my bad.

Comment: Great, thanks. I understand why I was confused now.

Answer (score 0):

What are your rules?  A good answer will depend upon what you consider a valid argument.  A simple proof is the following:  If ~A then A→B and so A→(A→B) and hence (A→(A→B))→(A→B).  Otherwise, assume A.  If A→B is true, we are done; otherwise, assume that A→B is false.  But then A→(A→B) is false and hence (A→(A→B)) → (A →B) is true